# Lingo call to ActionScript not working

Tags: flash, actionscript, lingo

I have a Flash sprite in my Director project. Under the Properties of that sprite, under both the Member and the Sprite tabs, it has as its name "Assessment". In my Lingo script, I have the following call:

```
sprite("Assessment").displayGrade(75, 3, 4)
```

where displayGrade is a function defined in the Flash object's ActionScript as a method taking 3 numbers as parameters. However, I get an error on this line, and cannot determine why. Am I calling the Flash object's method incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I browsed a little and I found this one:

http://groups.google.com/group/macromedia.director.basics/browse_thread/thread/85203d2879267fe1?pli=1

and this too:

http://dreamweaverforum.info/director/23160-director-11-actionscript-3-a.html

Of course, you should verify by browsing the Director 11 docs.

Regards,
Vyger

Comment: Thanks for the searches, it seems to be what I keep coming up with. As far as I know, there's no particular reason for our use of AS3, would an earlier version be better? Is there a way for me to just create 3 variables in Flash and then call setVariable for each one?

Comment: Not sure if a previous version could be better: that is, the links I posted seem to suggest AS3 is your problem. Anyway, I would browse Director 11 documentation to be sure "enough". It would be quite simple to build an AS2 swf file and try to call a Flash custom function.

Comment: I checked using AS 2, and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a thing about the Director side, but since this isn't resolved yet I'll ask: how are you doing things on the Flash side?

- You said your SWF uses AS3, but AS2 and AS3 use completely different engines, so it's very possible that Director can call one but not the other, or that the method differs. Testing with a simple AS2 SWF might help.
- Where are you defining your function in Flash? If your member Sprite is referring to a SWF, then I'd think you likely want the function to be on the main timeline of the flash file. But if your member Sprite is referring to an actual Sprite in the flash movie, then that wouldn't work, and you would need the function to be defined inside the Sprite (or the class attached to the sprite, perhaps).
- If there's any doubt about the Flash side, have you tried to call flash methods that are built-in (and hence guaranteed to be present)? If the movie has more than one frame in its top level, you could try calling methods like play(), stop(), or gotoAndStop(n:Number). If there is only one frame then it's not so easy, as most other methods wouldn't have an obvious visual effect.

Apologies in advance if you're already sure the Flash part is okay. These are only guesses.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't develop the Flash movie, but I know it's written using AS3. The function is in the "action layer" on the first frame of the movie. Can you provide an example of another method I can call?

Comment: Sure.. I'll edit into the answer because of the length limit on comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

set up a container-content reference to your swf, 
that is the Flash main timeline:

```
global swfTL
on beginSprite me
swfTL = getvariable(sprite('yourFlashSprite'),'_level0',False)
end
```

then call

`swfTL.displayGrade(75, 3, 4)`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I get a compiler error of Variable used before assigning a value when I try that. The error is on the on beginSprite me function.

Comment: Hi, when I posted I assumed you were using DirectorMX: here you can find solutions for MX and MX2004: http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_18541. The software version is very important.

Comment: Aside from the technote example, you could try changing the beginSprite handler with 

on mouseup me OR exitframe me

My suspect is that beginSprite executes before the Flash Player is instanciated

Comment: Other issues could be caused by conflicting versions: as far as I know, in Director MX you can call Flash MX (Player 6, AS 1) functions

Comment: I'm using Flash CS 3 with ActionScript 3 and Director 11.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Flash sprite in my Director project. Under the Properties of that sprite, under both the Member and the Sprite tabs, it has as its name "first". In my Lingo script, I have the following call:

sprite("first").number1

where number1 is a variable defined in the Flash object's ActionScript3 :a=25 in flash. However,in director return , but if swf cteate in ActionScript2 return 25 ! 
what is syntax in as3 for get variable from flash(swf) inside director (if swf created in as3)?